# Should I edit the code listing in my question with the corrections in accepted answer so that it's valid code?

Tags: discussion, edits

In this question, [Self clearing an interval inside jquery.each()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855622/self-clearing-interval-inside-jquery-each) there was a minor omission in my code. A responder drew my attention to it and I accepted the answer. Should I correct the code in the question so that it's correct, for other users to be able to use it? Or is it bad to rewrite history?

I will, of course, comment the edited lines as `//fixed as per accepted answer`.

Comment: +1 for asking the question to learn the proper way to do things :)

Answer (score 12):

No, don't do it.

The answer was given in the context of the question, that is - wrong code.

If you correct the question, the answer is now meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show that you solved it, accept the answer that you used, and think about leaving a comment on the answer that says "thanks". If you fixed it yourself, and nobody else got it, answer your own question with the correct code. **If nobody else has correctly answered your question**, then accept your own answer.

Comment: A comment that says nothing but "thanks" is useless.

Comment: It simply shows that you have gained useful information from an answer. Many of us simply like to know that we are giving back to a community that has helped us, and don't care about rep.

Comment: Accepting an answer indicates that you found it useful. Comments like "thanks, that worked perfectly!" are harmless as a social nicety perhaps, but are entirely unnecessary.